# Relatively new to python and I'm trying to program a quiz that ask the user for multiple inputs and checks them with the dictionary of answers

Tags: python

I understand I need another for loop or while loop in order to run through the lists inside answer_inputs but I am have trouble with it. I understand that this is sort of a short answers test but there only a few answers possible per question.

```
  questions = ["What are the three elements of a firing team?",
         "What command level does a FiST belong to and what are its elements?",
         "What Command level does a FSCC belong to and what are its elements?",
         "What are the Fire Support Planning Phases?",
         "What are the two general types of targets?"]

 answer_inputs = [{"1.","\n2.","\n3.\n"},
             {"Level:","\n1.","\n2.","\n3.","\n4.","\n5.\n"},
             {"Level:","\n1.","\n2.","\n3.","\n4.","\n5.\n"},
             {"1.\n2.\n3.\n"},
             {"1.\n2.\n"}]

one = "observer" or "FDC" or "Howitzer" or "M777" or "155mm"

two = "Company FiST Leader" or "Forward Air Controller" or "FAC" or "Fire Support officer" or "Artillery FO" or "81mm Mortar Observer (FO)" or "Naval Gun-fire spotter team"

three = "Fire Support Coordinator" or "Tactical Air control Party"  or "TACP" or "Liaison section" or "81mm mortar section" or "Shore Fire control Party"

four = "preperatory" or "conduct"  or "consolidation"

five = "linear" or "point"

correct_choices = [{one,one,one},
               {"Company", two, two, two, two, two},
               {"Battalion", three, three, three, three, three},
               {four, four, four},
               {"linear" or "point","linear" or "point"}]

answers = ["Observer\nFDC\nHowitzer or M777 or 155mm",
       "Level:Company\n1.Company FiST Leader\n2.Forward Air Controller (FAC)\n3.Fire Support officer (artillery FO)\n4.81mm Mortar Observer (FO)\n5.Naval Gun-fire spotter team\n:",
       "Level:Battalion\n1.Fire Support Coordinator\n2.\n3.\n4.\n5.\n:",
       "preperatory, conduct and consolidation",
       "linear and point"]

def quiz():

score = 0

for question, choices, correct_choice, answer in zip(questions, answer_inputs, correct_choices, answers):

    print(question)

    user_answer = input(choices).lower().rstrip("s")

    if user_answer in correct_choices:
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect",print("_"*10), answer)
print(score, "out of", len(questions), "that is", float(score / len(questions)) * 100, "%")

if __name__ == "__main__":
quiz()
```

Comment: Hello Joseph, can i provide a sample Quiz program in python?

Comment: Sure man! What do you have?

Comment: A sample Quiz program in python which i have made when i was in 1st semester

Comment: Yea, just know I can't make this a multiple choice quiz

Comment: ok wait Joseph Braden

Comment: Joseph Braden this answers helps you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Sample Multiple choice quiz.

```
import random

class QA:
    def __init__(self, question, correctAnswer, otherAnswers):
        self.question = question
        self.corrAnsw = correctAnswer
        self.otherAnsw = otherAnswers


qaList = [QA("Where is Minsk?", "in Belarus", ["in Russia", "such a city doesn't exist"]),
          QA("What is the capital of Australia?", "Canberra", ["Sydney", "New York", "Australia doesn't exist"]),
          QA("Which of the following is not on Earth?", "Sea of Tranquility",
             ["Mediterranean Sea", "Baltic Sea", "North Sea"]),
          QA("Which of the following is not a continent?", "Arctica", ["Antarctica", "America"]),
          QA("Which of the following is not an African country?", "Malaysia",
             ["Madagascar", "Djibouti", "South Africa", "Zimbabwe"])]

corrCount = 0
random.shuffle(qaList)
for qaItem in qaList:
    print(qaItem.question)
    print("Possible answers are:")
    possible = qaItem.otherAnsw + [
        qaItem.corrAnsw]  # square brackets turn correct answer into list for concatenating with other list
    random.shuffle(possible)
    count = 0  # list indexes start at 0 in python
    while count < len(possible):
        print(str(count + 1) + ": " + possible[count])
        count += 1
    print("Please enter the number of your answer:")
    userAnsw = input()
    while not userAnsw.isdigit():
        print("That was not a number. Please enter the number of your answer:")
        userAnsw = input()
    userAnsw = int(userAnsw)
    while not (userAnsw > 0 and userAnsw <= len(possible)):
        print("That number doesn't correspond to any answer. Please enter the number of your answer:")
        userAnsw = input()
    if possible[userAnsw - 1] == qaItem.corrAnsw:
        print("Your answer was correct.")
        corrCount += 1
    else:
        print("Your answer was wrong.")
        print("Correct answer was: " + qaItem.corrAnsw)
    print("")

print("You answered " + str(corrCount) + " of " + str(len(qaList)) + " questions correctly.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution i cobbled up for multiple correct answers. Quiz generation part can be skipped if you really want to hardcode but i recommend that you store your questions in a file like txt or json to be read later instead.

```
import random

questions = []
answers = []
options = []

# questions and answers generation

while True:
    question = str(input("Enter a question: (type done to finish) "))
    if question == "done":
        break
    questions.append(question)
    answer = ""
    nested_answers = []
    while True:
        answer = str(input("Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) "))
        if answer == "done":
            answers.append(nested_answers)
            break
        nested_answers.append(answer)
    nested_options = []
    while True:
        option = str(input("Enter a (wrong) option: (type done to finish) "))
        if option == "done":
            options.append(nested_options)
            break
        nested_options.append(option)

score = 0

for i in range(len(questions)):
    question = questions[i]
    print("\nQuestion " + str(i + 1) + ": " + question)
    combined_options = options[i] + answers[i]
    random.shuffle(combined_options)
    print("Options")
    for count, item in enumerate(combined_options, 1):
        print(str(count) + ": " + item)
    user_answer = int(input("Enter your answer (number): "))
    user_choice = combined_options[user_answer - 1]
    if user_choice in answers[i]:
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong :(")
print("Final score: " + str(score))
```

Sample run:

```
Enter a question: (type done to finish) which of these are fruits 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) apple 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) pear 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) orange 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) done 
Enter a (wrong) option: (type done to finish) lettuce 
Enter a (wrong) option: (type done to finish) broccoli 
Enter a (wrong) option: (type done to finish) done 
Enter a question: (type done to finish) which of these are vegetables 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) lettuce 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) cabbage 
Enter a correct answer: (type done to finish) done 
Enter a (wrong) option: (type done to finish) cat 
Enter a (wrong) option: (type done to finish) done 
Enter a question: (type done to finish) done

Question 1: which of these are fruits 
Options 
1: apple 
2: lettuce 
3: broccoli 
4: pear 
5: orange 
Enter your answer (number): 1 
Correct

Question 2: which of these are vegetables 
Options 1: cat 
2: cabbage 
3: lettuce 
Enter your answer (number): 2 
Correct 
Final score: 2
```